# iterating through item of array of generic collections

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I need a GetEnumerator on this class, to be able to iterate through any item of array A. How do I do that?

```
IObsColDoor[] A = {
    new IObsColDoor<S1>(),
    new IObsColDoor<S2>() 
   };

public interface IObsColDoor { }

public class ObsColDoor<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, IObsColDoor
    where T : new()
{
    public ObsColDoor() { }
    public ObsColDoor(int n = 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            this.Add(new T());
    }
}
```

use it like this:

```
IObsColDoor b = A[0];
```

use b:

```
id(b);
```

.....

```
void id(IObsColDoor d)
{
    foreach (T1 si in d) {  etc   };
```

where T1 is base class of S1 and S2

Comment: What class do you mean? `ObsColDoor<T>` already has `GetEnumerator`, since it is inherited from `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Comment: Still I get: "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type '.IObsColDoor' because 'IObsColDoor' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Comment: ooo, hold on: I'm confusing type IObsColDoor<T> and type T...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare `IObsColDoor` variables, and use them in `foreach`, you need to inherit `IObsColDoor` from [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public interface IObsColDoor : IEnumerable { }
```

Since `ObsColDoor<T>` is an `ObservableCollection<T>`, you don't need to implement `IEnumerable` in `ObsColDoor<T>` class, because it is already implemented.

Note, that:

- since `IObsColDoor` have not any generic functionality, you have to use `IEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`
- any other implementations of `IObsColDoor` must implement `IEnumerable` too.